# What tools can be used to find which DLLs are referenced?

Tags: dll, vb6, reference

This is an antique problem with VB6 DLL and COM objects but I still face it day to day. What tools or procedures can be used to see which DLL file or version another DLL is referencing?

I am referring to compiled DLLs at runtime, not from within VB6 IDE.

It's DLL hell.

Comment: This is already closed, but its a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303331/determine-which-dll-and-or-ocx-files-are-actually-used-by-my-program/51271331#51271331

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) shows you all the files that a DLL links to (or is trying to link to) and it's free.

Comment: Dependency walker wont catch COM dlls used by the dll, as these are loaded at runtime.

Comment: It is still a kick-ass program

Answer (score 6):

[ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) shows you all the DLLs that are currently loaded in a process at a particular moment. This gives you another angle on [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which I believe does a static scan and can miss some DLLs that are dynamically loaded on demand. Raymond says [that's unavoidable](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/07/10/9827869.aspx).