# COM Dll Dependency tree

Tags: c#, vb6

I have a project with some C# dlls that use other vb6 dlls. I also have vb6 dlls that use other vb6 dlls. I would like to map all these dependencies, so I'll know which vb6 dlls are still used.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you still have the .vbp project files around for the VB6 DLLs? I don't think there's an easy way to pull COM dependency information out of a compiled VB6 DLL. Of course, even then, there may be dependencies listed that aren't actually used.

Comment: I have the .vbp files. I want to see a tree with all the dependencies to any vb6 object from any other project.

Comment: Part of your question is a duplicate of this question [best tool to find which DLL another VB6 DLL is referenced to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69538/what-is-the-best-tool-to-find-which-dll-another-vb6-dll-is-referenced-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take a piece of paper and write on it the name of all your DLLs. Then you take a pen and draw an arrow from DLL A to DLL B if DLL A has a dependency on DLL B.

After that, you know that a DLL is unused if there are no arrows pointing towards it.

What you have now is a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG) -- it's probably not a tree, since you might have a DLL A that references DLLs B and C, both of which reference DLL D.

Since every DAG induces a partial order, you can take a fresh piece of paper and redraw your graph such that the DLLs that *are* dependencies are below the DLLs which *have them*  as dependencies, which will make a useful reference sheet.