# AxMSForms COM library is missing

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, vb6-migration

I've got an old vb application that was developed in VS 2003. I carefully upgraded it to vs 2015. This application uses some COM libraries. When I try to build the application, It gives an error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30002 Type 'AxMSForms.AxImage' is not defined
```

I found that some dll named AxMSForms.dll is causing the issue. Where to get those COM library files.

Feel free to ask if the question is not clear.

Comment: From what I could find those appear to be controls used by Office VBA. Why just don't replace them with native .NET controls? I.e. the [**`PictureBox`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You've tagged this as VB6, but I'm not sure what VB6 has to do with the question. Could you clarify?

Comment: @VisualVincent Can you make it clear?
I suspect this is an Activex controller. Activex controllers can be replaced?
If yes, please help with a link or anything. Thank you

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. That I'm not sure. But I think it's vb.net, because the project file has extension .vbproj. But these ActivexControls are part of Vb6 only right?

Comment: Did you mean _"controller"_ or _"controls"_? If the former, I have no idea what that is. If the latter, sure. Why wouldn't you be able to replace them? It does of course depend on what the control is used for, but if what I said in my initial comment is accurate (I have no idea, it's just what it seems to be based on what I could find) then there shouldn't be anything special to it that the `PictureBox` can't do.

Comment: And there's nothing special to replacing an ActiveX _control_ with a native one. Just remove it from your form(s) and add a `PictureBox` from the toolbox instead (backup your project before doing this! Again, I'm not sure whether I'm right or not). Though you might need to rewrite your code a little since I doubt they share the same set of properties and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that an `Ax.....dll` file is automatically created by Visual Studio when you add a reference to an ActiveX `OCX` file to a VB.NET (or C#) project.

You should try *removing and then re-adding the reference to the OCX from your project*. This may get Visual Studio to rebuild the wrapper DLLs. That has worked for me in the past.

**Explanation:**

An ActiveX control is always (?) packaged in an `OCX` file which is just a type of COM DLL which therefore uses COM objects to represent the controls it supplies.

.NET code can't directly utilize COM objects, so the dev tools will create wrapper classes which provide access to them for you. OCX DLLs are a sort of special case because Visual Studio will not only provide a COM wrapper, but ALSO will provide a wrapper that maps the ActiveX control to a Windows Forms control. That specifically is what the missing AX DLL would have contained.

Comment: These Activex controls are coming as a part of vb 6.0 sp 6 packages? Because, when I take a build of this application and installs it on a pc where vs 2005 is installed, its running fine. But when I install and then run the same build on another pc where VS 2005 is not there, It shows 'somedll.dll is or its dependency is missing'.

Comment: In their day ActiveX controls came both with VB6 (ie Microsoft) and also from other vendors. If you are not sure what your dependencies are, maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303331/determine-which-dll-and-or-ocx-files-are-actually-used-by-my-program

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out