# UN identified and Unregistered library,. but not on all machines

Tags: com, vb6

Two Windows 11 machines; One runs my VB6 App, the other beeps once and aborts with "Object library not registered" Note it does not identify the culprit.

I've tried deleting and re-registering the objects I know about without success. They are olepro32.dll, comglg32.dll, mfc42.dll, ss32x25.ocx, and vbprndlg.dll.

Comment: Do you still have the source code?  If so, look at the References for your app.

Comment: The fact that it works on SOME machines means that they happen to have one or more dependencies registered, and the other ones do not. As Brian mentioned, if you have the soruce code (VBP files specifically) you can check what the DLL or OCX references are and discover anything you have not accounted for. If you don't have that - or if the problem is dependencies of dependencies... use Process Monitor to find out specifically what its failing on. Not simple but no other practical approach.

Comment: Ultimately you should create an installer to deploy all needed dependencies properly. Otherwise this kind of situation is very common with VB6 programs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine which DLL and/or OCX files are actually used by my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303331/determine-which-dll-and-or-ocx-files-are-actually-used-by-my-program)