How to examine VB code to determine what to use to register it?
I am not a product developer, I am an InstallShield Developer.  Working on an Installer that is old and may not be registering the DLLs correctly.  I am trying to determine if 'COM Extract at Build', or '.NET COM Interop' should be selected for the installer components that are DLLs.  The product is VB 6 and VB .NET.
I can search through the code (code\Net folder) and look for things like "true" in the .vbproj files.  If true then I should select '.NET COM Interop'?  If false select what in InstallShield?
What do I look for in the code to determine if I should be using 'COM Extract at Build'.  Would that be anything in the Code Base (code\VB6 folder)?
Basically, what to look for in the actual code, that will tell ne whether regsvr32 or regasm should be used?  Also is there something in the code that will indicate if a 32 bit or 64 bit version should be used?
Thanks.
Thanks

.Net dlls do not normally need to be registered at all... but if the product is mixing platforms there could be more going on here.

As for 32bit  vs 64bit, it should be a 32bit app if it mixes with vb6, because vb6 was never updated for 64bit. But it's possible the developers haven't accounted for this and left the .Net solution set for the default "AnyCPU" setting, which allows you to build one set of assemblies that will do both. When the program runs, the Framework runtime will JIT compile for whichever matches the local system. But this is unlikely here, since I'd expect it to break on 64bit systems if you have to load 32bit libraries.

And be aware: there's a lot of talk the next Windows (Windows 12?) will fully drop 32-bit and go 64-bit only, which would imply vb6 support will be gone, too

Hum, that would break a lot of office and VBA code - including Excel of which millions still use.  Now, the last few versions of office does now have a x64 bit version, but both Sage accounting and QuickBooks don't have x64 bit versions of their main accounting packages - so that's going to be a challenge. I doubt that the last 20 years of software packages like accounting systems will have to be tossed out due to no more x32 bit support in windows.

We don't have  your code base - we are just as blind as you are here. So, only the .net code files would need a regasm, and the vb6 ones would not. (they might need a regsvr32, but again we would have to see the application). I don't believe you can JUST BE a installer developer and not have VAST knowledge of the code base - it simply not possible to do as such without HIGH familiarly of the the code base, and anyone who thinks overwise is delusional. In other words, due to a mix of managed and non managed code, building such an installer will require high first knowledge of the code base.

@JoelCoehoorn: the .NET assembly might be set to "Register for COM interop", providing otherwise hard to achieve features to the VB6 application. IN that case, a similar named typelib should exist with which the .NET assembly needs to be registered.

The root of the question is valid but the details are sparse and confusing / contradictory. Is this VB6 or VB.Net or both?

For VB6 some of the information you need is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51271331/3195477
